# How to install Ms Virtual PC in Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, microsoft-virtual-pc

My server doesn't have Hyper-V feature and I need to launch a virtual pc image on it.

I tried installing from this [Microsoft link](http://www.google.com.vn/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx&ei=u_HATefgIZOWhQeLwcCvBQ&usg=AFQjCNHkkPbWGv_jWBsetHJGSH89DcBxag) but failed.

Is it a workaround for me? Please help.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [this update to Server 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=6F69D661-5B91-4E5E-A6C0-210E629E1C42)?

Comment: Why do I need to install that Neal?

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly MS Virtual Server 2008 will run on Windows 2008 but isn't supported.

Why not use Hyper-V: it will work with Virtual PC guests?  (You'll need to replace the virtual machine additions with the Hyper-V installer to get full integration—as was needed with Virtual Server and Virtual PC updates.)

Comment: Not using Hyper-V just because of the licences Richard :)

Comment: @NamGiVU: 2k8 includes H-V, and guest OS's need their own licences as they do with Virtual PC. Actually less: 2k8 in the right edition includes licences for the first few, or with Data Center unlimited, guest instances of 2008. (Some early builds of 2k8 had H-V as extra $$$, but shortly after MS changed it so H-V was included: I assumed the change was retrospective.)